# String not recognised in for each loop

Tags: vb.net

If I do the loop and write "ComputerName" arguments, it displays them so that works!
but when I add the actual code I want it to work with it fails, I don't understand why ?

If I run the loop but hard code the ComputerName variable I'm testing with it works i.e. `ComputerName = "computer01"`

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'to be tested later
        '-------------------

        'Dim co As New ConnectionOptions
        'co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate
        'co.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
        'co.EnablePrivileges = True

        'co.Username = username
        'co.Password = password

        'Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\" & machine.Text & "\root\cimv2", co)

        'scope.Connect()
        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        For Each ComputerName As String In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

            Dim uninstallKey As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
            'Using rk As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey)

            Using rk As RegistryKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ComputerName, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(uninstallKey)

                Dim Applications As New List(Of String)()

                For Each skName As String In rk.GetSubKeyNames()
                    Using sk As RegistryKey = rk.OpenSubKey(skName)

                        If Not CStr(sk.GetValue("DisplayName")) = "" Then
                            Try
                                Applications.Add(CStr(sk.GetValue("DisplayName")) & " " & CStr(sk.GetValue("DisplayVersion")))
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Console.WriteLine("!!!!!! error: " & ex.Message)
                            End Try
                        End If

                    End Using
                Next

                Applications.Sort()
                For Each app As String In Applications
                    Console.WriteLine(app)
                Next

            End Using

        Next ComputerName

        Console.Write("Press any key to exit . . .")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What computer names are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I changed this

```
Sub Main()

    For Each ComputerName As String In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

to this

```
Sub Main(args() As String)

    For Each ComputerName As String In args
```

and that seems to work ? any other \ better way I should do it ?

Comment: Have you inspected what `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns? The first element in the array is always the full path of the application. Which doesn't work very well as computer name.

Comment: OH! I didn't know this.